# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #13 has length 1; 2 is required

Tags: python, dictionary

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-ec485c9b9711> in <module>
     31     except Exception as e:
     32         print(e)
---> 33         raise e
     34     print(i)
     35     i = i+1

<ipython-input-19-ec485c9b9711> in <module>
     21 #                 cc = dict(x.split(':') for x in c.split(','))
     22                 c = '"'.join(c)
---> 23                 cc = dict(x.split(':') for x in c.split(','))
     24                 df_temp = pd.DataFrame(cc.items())
     25                 df_temp = df_temp.replace('"','',regex=True)

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #13 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Below is the block which is throwing the error. I checked out some of the posts here but they are code specific. Not sure is it input issue or the code.

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame()
i=1
for file in files:
    try:
        s3 = session.resource('s3')
        key = file
        obj = s3.Object('my-bucket',key)
        n = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        gzipfile = BytesIO(n)
        gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipfile)
        content = gzipfile.read()
        content = content.decode('utf-8')
        if len(content) > 0:
            content = re.findall(r"(?<=\{)(.*?)(?=\})",content)
            for c in content:
                c= c.split('"')
                for index,val in enumerate(c):
                    if index%2 == 1:
                        c[index] = val.replace(':','_').replace(',','_')
                c = '"'.join(c)
                cc = dict(x.split(':') for x in c.split(','))
                df_temp = pd.DataFrame(cc.items())
                df_temp = df_temp.replace('"','',regex=True)
                df_temp = df_temp.T
                new_header = df_temp.iloc[0] #grab the first row for the header
                df_temp = df_temp[1:] #take the data less the header row
                df_temp.columns = new_header
                df_final = pd.concat([df_final, df_temp])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise e
    print(i)
    i = i+1
```

Can you share what is the issue here? This used to work fine before. Do I make a change or ignore the error?

Comment: Can't tell the problem without seeing the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your data is malformed.  I'm guessing that at some point, `x.split(':')` is producing a list with only one element in it because there is no `:` in `x`, the string being split.  This leads, during the creation of a dictionary from this data, to a single value being passed when a pair of values (for "key" and "value") is expected.

I would suggest that you fire up your debugger and either let the debugger stop when it hits this error, or figure out when it happens and get to a point where you're just about to have the error occur.  Then look at the data that's being or about to be processed in your debugger display and see if you can find this malformed data that is causing the problem.  You might have to run a prep pass on the data to fix this problem and others like it before running the line that is throwing the exception.

Comment: Yes, I think that is possible because I am not handling the ingestion of the data, looks like the data file has the issue. Is it possible to just ignore that and keep scanning other files from the loop?